# Sharing Authentication Cookie in ASP.NET 5 across subdomains

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on, asp.net-core

I have two ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 applications.

One is running at `www.mydomain.tld` and one at `world1.mydomain.tld`.

If a user gets logged in on www subdomain's application, I want her to be logged in on world1 subdomain's application as well. The login is realized with ASP.NET Identity 3.

I've set up both applications in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
    // [...]

    services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSession(
        options => {
            options.CookieDomain = ".mydomain.tld";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        }
    );

    // [...]
}

public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory) {
    // [...]

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(null, IdentityOptions.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(null, IdentityOptions.TwoFactorRememberMeCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(null, IdentityOptions.TwoFactorUserIdCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(
        config => {
            config.CookieDomain = ".mydomain.tld";
        },
        IdentityOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme
    );

    // [...]
}
```

I've also set the machine key of both applications via `web.config` as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey decryption="AES"
                decryptionKey="SOME DECRYPTION KEY"
                validation="HMACSHA256"
                validationKey="SOME ENCRYPTION KEY" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Logging in on www subdomain works, but accessing sites on world1 subdomain doesn't work, because the authentication cookie is not being recognized as a valid login cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apps are [automatically isolated](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html#data-protection-configuration-per-app-isolation) from one another. You need to ensure three things;

1. They use the same key store
2. They use the same application ID.
3. They're in the same app pool, or the identity on each pool is identical.

Apps running on the same host, under the same hosting mechanism will use the same key store. If these are on separate machines you will need to use a key store on a network drive, or other shared place such as azure blob storage.

In order to set an application ID common to both applications you need to [configure](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html#data-protection-configuration-per-app-isolation) the data protection stack.

For example,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection();
    services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
    {
        configure.SetApplicationName("my application");
    });
}
```

If you need to run the applications as different users then you need to change how the keys are protected to either use machine level DPAPI or an X509 certificate.

You don't need a machine key entry in your web.config, machine key is no longer users.

Comment: I added the lines at the beginning of the `ConfigureServices` method, but it didn't work either. :( Both applications are running on the same host in IIS 8.5.

Comment: Are they running in the same app pool?

Comment: No, each application has its own app pool.

Comment: Put them in the same app pool, under the same identity. Keys are locked to identities as well. Or configure the protection of the key store to be something common like X509.

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I now store the keys of the www-application via `PersistKeysToFileSystem` and want to load the saved keys into the world1-application, but I don't find a way to load them. My goal is to make it possible to run both applications on different machines. How can I do this?

Comment: At that point you'd point both apps to a network share as their key store. However now your keys are unprotected by default, because we can't use DPAPI any more. You need to also use an X509 cert to protect the keys, and make sure it's on both machines. This is covered in the configuration docs - http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html

Comment: It's working now. It took a bit longer, because I forgot to set the private key's permissions to grant access to the application pools. Thank you!

Comment: I just updated to beta 8 and now it doesn't work anymore. I get this message: warning: [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker] Authorizati on failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizeFilter'.

Comment: Works now. I had to set the options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieDomain of the IdentityOptions, too.